# Spinning multiple environments from single backup file

Tags: sql-server, replication, restore

I am having a unique situation where my production database size 5TB (SQLSrv) which needs to be replicated across 4 servers daily. I am looking for an option where all 4 environments can use a single backup file as the source and continue to perform the write operation **in isolation** thereafter. It will save a lot of disk space and restoration time (3hours per env)

Comment: To clarify, your goal is to have a single **full backup** as a starting point for 4 servers, and then you want to just backup the changes that have occurred since the **full backup**, separately, for each server?

Comment: yes, that is correct without changing the full backup file with each environment has its own file to read/write.

Comment: You don't say anything about your environment but most SANs have some sort of snapshot or fast copy facility which might be helpful.
One place I worked had a 4 node cluster and took the backup to a SAN disk, then reattached it to a different node and ran the restore - no file copy required.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to look into 3rd party solutions, you can try SQL Clone by Redgate.
It will created virtual data files and virtual delta files. These files combined will be presented to SQL Server and it will be treated as a separate copies of the database.

You can find documentation here: https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-clone

Comment: I believe that Veeam has a similar functionality, but the name eludes of that functionality eludes me. As for Veeam, I know one want to be careful regarding performance overhead having these "snapshots" being long-lived. I can't speak for Redgate in that aspect, but just to mention it...

Comment: Thanks, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just manually take a single **Full Backup** of the first server and then use that to restore the other servers from initially. Then setup a maintenance plan or job to only take **Differential Backups** and/or **Transaction Log Backups** of the other servers stored to separate locations. The **Full Backup** you can keep in a universally accessible network location for your four servers though.
You can read up more on the different backup types [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-sql-server-backup-types/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-overview-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Following this process might save you the space of storing multiple **Full Backups** but it won't save you any time should you need to do a restore since the initial **Full Backup** still needs to be restored from first before the **Differential** and **Transaction Log Backups** can be applied. And in fact, because newer **Differential Backups** will generally grow over time, the further away they are from the initial **Full Backup**, and because the amount of backup files SQL Server will need to process will be a lot more than usual, I'd suspect your recovery time would take significantly longer this way.

Typically you'd want to setup routine **Full Backups** in your maintenance plan, and have it delete old backup files, to reclaim space. This way the amount of data you're restoring isn't starting from a base backup from years ago, and the number of files needed to restore could be in the hundreds of thousands.

Of course in your situation, that would cost you more disk space upfront. Even only keeping one copy of the most recent **Full Backup** would have to be four **Full Backup** files, one for each of your servers, since their data will vary after the initial creation. But it would definitely be the better way to go in terms of recovery time.

So you'll have to decide between how much disk space you can afford vs what your recovery time objectives are, and it is a balance.